# Model class not found in .../magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:93

Tags: magento2, error, collection, magento2.1.6, factory

When I try to load collection via `getCollection` method in my custom Block, I get this error in apache2 log.

The complete error is:

> [Mon May 08 09:53:53.485661 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 1996:tid 140084720269056] [client 127.0.0.1:50323] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message:
> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class **'Ciptaloka\\HelloWorld\\Model\\HelloWorld'** not found in /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:93
>   Stack trace:
>   #0 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(88): Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\AbstractFactory->createObject('Ciptaloka\\Hello...', Array)
>   #1 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(57): Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Compiled->create('Ciptaloka\\Hello...', Array)
>   #2 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/var/generation/Ciptaloka/HelloWorld/Model/HelloWorldFactory.php(43): Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\ObjectManager->create('Ciptaloka\\Hello...', Array)
>   #3 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/Ciptaloka/HelloWorld/Block/Catalog/Product/HelloWorld.php(75): Ciptaloka\\HelloWorld\\Model\\HelloWorldFactory->create()
>   #4 [internal function]: Ciptaloka\\HelloWorld\\Block\\Catalog\\P...
> ', referer: http://192.168.1.171/

This is the directory structure of my custom module:

```
app/code/Ciptaloka/HelloWorld/
├── Block
│   └── Catalog
│       └── Product
│           └── HelloWorld.php
├── etc
│   ├── adminhtml
│   │   ├── routes.xml
│   │   └── system.xml
│   ├── config.xml
│   └── module.xml
├── Helper
│   └── ConfigurationHelper.php
├── Model
│   ├── HelloWorld.php
│   ├── ResourceModel
│   │   ├── HelloWorld
│   │   │   └── Collection.php
│   │   └── HelloWorld.php
│   └── Source
│       └── TextAlign.php
├── registration.php
├── Setup
│   └── InstallSchema.php
└── view
    └── frontend
        ├── layout
        │   └── catalog_product_view.xml
        ├── templates
        │   └── product
        │       └── hello.phtml
        └── web
            └── css
                └── hello.css
```

As you can see in the dir tree, Ciptaloka\HelloWorld\Model\HelloWorld does exist. And this is the file content of it:

```
<?php

namespace Ciptloka\HelloWorld\Model;

use \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;

class HelloWorld extends AbstractModel
{
    /**
     * Model constructor
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Ciptaloka\HelloWorld\Model\ResourceModel\HelloWorld');
    }
}
```

And the other files;

**Model/ResourceModel/HelloWorld.php** (The table `ciptaloka_helloworld` is defined.):

```
<?php

namespace Ciptaloka\HelloWorld\Model\ResourceModel;

use \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;

class HelloWorld extends AbstractDb
{
    /**
     * Model initialization
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('ciptaloka_helloworld', 'id');
    }
}
```

**Model/ResourceModel/HelloWorld/Collection.php**:

```
<?php

namespace Ciptaloka\HelloWorld\Model\ResourceModel\HelloWorld;

use \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    /**
     * Collection constructor
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(
            'Ciptaloka\HelloWorld\Model\HelloWorld',
            'Ciptaloka\HelloWorld\Model\ResourceModel\HelloWorld'
        );
    }
}
```

the generated factory **var/generation/Ciptaloka/HelloWorld/Model/HelloWorldFactory.php**:

```
<?php

namespace Ciptaloka\HelloWorld\Model;

class HelloWorldFactory
{
    protected $_objectManager = null;

    protected $_instanceName = null;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager, $instanceName = 'Ciptaloka\\HelloWorld\\Model\\HelloWorld')
    {
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->_instanceName = $instanceName;
    }

    public function create(array $data = array())
    {
        return $this->_objectManager->create($this->_instanceName, $data);
    }
}
```

and, the Block file:

```
<?php

namespace Ciptaloka\HelloWorld\Block\Catalog\Product;

use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use \Ciptaloka\HelloWorld\Helper\ConfigurationHelper;
use \Ciptaloka\HelloWorld\Model\HelloWorldFactory;

class HelloWorld extends Template
{
    /**
     * @var ConfigurationHelper
     */
    protected $_helper;

    /**
     * @var HelloWorldFactory
     */
    protected $_helloWorldFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        HelloWorldFactory $helloWorldFactory,
        array $data = [],
        ConfigurationHelper $helper
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_helloWorldFactory = $helloWorldFactory;
        $this->_helper = $helper;
    }

    /**
     * Returns 'Hello World!' string
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
     */
    public function getHelloWorldTxt()
    {
        return __('Hello World!');
    }

    public function getBlockLabel()
    {
        return $this->_helper->getBlockLabel();
    }

    public function getTextAlign()
    {
        return $this->_helper->getTextAlign();
    }

    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        if ($this->_helper->getEnable()) {
            return parent::_toHtml();
        }
        else {
            return '';
        }
    }

    public function getCollection()
    {
        return $this->_helloWorldFactory->create()->getCollection();
    }
}
```

Do I make any mistake here that caused that error? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Replace `class HelloWorld extends AbstractDb` with `class HelloWorld extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel`

Comment: @AnkitShah replacing the one in `Model/ResourceModel/HelloWorld.php`? Is that the same as the one inherited in Model file?

Comment: Sorry ignore it. Please follow https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/

Comment: Did you try after delete  var/generation/* and clear cache?

Comment: @AnkitShah I tried creating model interface and implementing abstract methods based on the link you provided, but it still give me the same error as stated in my question.

Comment: @SohelRana Yes, I tried doing `setup:di:compile` and deleting the directory manually and `cache:clean` and `cache:flush`.

Comment: Share your module then.

Comment: @SohelRana here is the link to my experiment custom module https://github.com/softtama/magento2module-helloworld. Looking forward for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have typo in your `app/code/Ciptaloka/HelloWorld/Model/HelloWorld.php` at `line 3`:

```
namespace Ciptloka\HelloWorld\Model;
```

It should be:

```
namespace Ciptaloka\HelloWorld\Model;
```

Notice the difference between `Ciptloka` and `Ciptaloka`.

Comment: Wow... how could my eyes miss that?! Thanks for spotting it! Everything works flawlessly now.